# Sine wave oscillator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

What circuit or ic can I use to produce sine wave with 30 kHz frequency and 9 Vp-p?

I used XR2206 but the maximum peak-to-peak voltage is 3 V and I need 9 Vp-p.

I will be using this for inductive power transfer. Is it ok if i will use signal generator instead of creating my own oscillator?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot consider adding an external stage to achieve that higher output range? Or is it okay to simply add a circuit?

Comment: Do you need 20Vp_p or 9 Vp_p ?

Comment: Xr2209 max Vp-p is 3v and i need 9Vp-p for sine wave oscillator. What circuit can i add to achieve higher Vp-p?

Comment: @Noel but your first sentence says 20 Vp-p. Please correct your question, if you only need 9 Vp-p.

Comment: And: using a function generator to generate a 30 kHz sine wave does sound a) unnecessarily expensive, b) unnecessarily complex, considering you probably have a modern microcontroller controlling that and could just directly generate an arbitrary 30 kHz waveform in software...

Comment: Thank you for correcting :)  i only need 9Vp-p for my sine wave oscillator.

Comment: If you are going to build an oscillator by your own. there are many solutions. My recommendation: Use any of the available opamp-based methods, but watch the slew rate of the selected opamp type.

Comment: To be honest, i dont have enough knowledge about slew rate because it was not discuss to me very well but thank you for your suggestion. Ill study first what is slew rate then ill try to look for opamps. Thank you

Comment: In your case (9Vpp and 30 kHz) the opamp should have a slew rate SR>3.5 V/µsec

Answer (score 1):

You could try to build a higher-voltage oscillator yourself. But, frankly, that's probably not worth the effort.

A simple op-amp based amplifier does what you need. I trust you'll find a good candidates when looking for "opamp amplifier circuit" e.g. on wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) i'll try to look for opamp amplifier circuit.